# CloudKit: does the default zone have the atomic capability?

Tags: cloudkit

I want to push data in an atomic way to the default zone.

Is it possible?

cf. Apple documentation:

> Modifying records atomically prevents you from updating your data in a
>   way that would leave it in an inconsistent state. You use atomic
>   updates when you want to write multiple records to the same record
>   zone. If there is a failure to modify any of the records in a
>   particular zone, no changes are made to the other records in that same
>   zone. The zone itself must have the CKRecordZoneCapabilityAtomic
>   capability for this behavior to apply. If a record zone does not
>   support the atomic capability, setting this property has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% clear, but when reading the documentation I would say atomic updates are not possible in the default zone.

From the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecordZone_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CKRecordZone/defaultRecordZone

> Custom zones support other capabilities too, such as the ability to
>   write multiple records as a single atomic transaction.

And also:

> The disadvantage of using the default zone for storing records is that
>   it does not have any special capabilities. You cannot save a group of
>   records to iCloud atomically in the default zone. Similarly, you
>   cannot use a CKFetchRecordChangesOperation object on records in the
>   default zone.

Comment: I don't see that second excerpt on the docs page anymore. I wonder if it changed